# return a varray from a function oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to return a varray from oracle function but I don't know how to do it.
Here is so far what I have tried.

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
   type array_t is varray(2) of number;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func() return array_t
begin
  array array_t :=array_t(0,0);   
  array(1):=3;
  array(2):=20;
  return array;
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hier is the right syntax for your function

```
 create  type array_t is varray(2) of number;
 /

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func return array_t
 IS
  v_array  array_t;
begin
  v_array  :=array_t(0,0);   
  v_array(1):=3;
  v_array(2):=20;
  return v_array;
end;
/
```

you can call the function for example in an anonymous plsql block

```
declare
  v_func_result array_t;
begin

 v_func_result := func();

 dbms_output.put_line(v_func_result(1));
 dbms_output.put_line(v_func_result(2));
 end;
/
```

Comment: @ schurik can u please also given an example on how to call this function.

Comment: select  func from dual;

Comment: @XING I mean when I try to call function like this v_array := func(); I get error.

Comment: @PrashantBhanarkar i have complete my answer with the example of the fucntion call

Comment: @schurik can we call this function from select query, any how?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to declare a procedure in the SQL scope; you can declare it as a [nested sub-program in an anonymous PL/SQL block](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  TYPE array_t IS VARRAY(2) OF NUMBER;

  data array_t;

  FUNCTION func RETURN array_t IS BEGIN RETURN array_t( 3, 20 ); END func;
BEGIN
  data := func();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '(' || data(1) || ', ' || data(2) || ')' );
END;
/
```